# Angular 2 : how to target an element's HTML attribute in an array

Tags: angular, angular2-template, image-gallery, photo-gallery

Project: Trying to create a simple image gallery. One main image placeholder, that changes its image to be have the same src as a corresponding thumbnail image that has been clicked.

Example in plain JS: 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tab_img_gallery

Code:

```
<div *ngIf="images">  

  <div *ngFor="let image of images"> //images array

    <img #productThumbnail [src]='image.fields.file.url' 
    (click)='thumbnailClicked()'>

    <div *ngIf='showImage'>//simple function that shows the image
      <img src={{productThumbnail.src}}>
    </div>
```

(image.fields.file.url is an external array (array name: images) of image URLs)

Problem:
When the images array is populated many array items will be given the reference #productThumbnail

This results in the main image placeholder retrieving the src of every thumbnail, because they all have the same reference of #productThumbnail. I just need the thumbnail that has been clicked on.

I hope this makes some sense. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Mimicking that, I think you'd want this:

```html
<img *ngFor="let image of images" 
    [src]='image.fields.file.url' 
    (click)='thumbnailClicked(image)'>
```

Have you stepped through the [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) yet? I think walking through that can help you to solve problems like this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daniel, and for spotting that I left out the ngFor statement. (I've updated the question to put it in). I got the above code from the Angular tutorial, which I did find helpful. I'll keep going through it.